# How do you return a meteor.call result from a meteor validated-method?

Tags: session, meteor, methods, return-value

Most of the examples already provided usually deal with a meteor.call inside a template. I am making a meteor.call from inside a validatedMethod and am expecting a result. I then want to return or pass this result back to the function calling the validatedMethod, but I can't find anything that works. Here is the code with a Session variable, but it causes an the error - "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getListsServer': TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined". I have also tried a local variable and a local ReactiveVar, but these seem to loose scope once they leave the meteor.call. I could use some help, thanks.

```js
export const getLists = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'ListsDB.methods.getLists',
    validate: new SimpleSchema({}).validator(),
    run({}) {
        Meteor.call('getListsServer', function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                //do something;
            } else {
                Session.set('getResults', result); //--> this is the line causing the error
            }
        });

        return Session.get('getResults');
    }
});


    Meteor.methods({
       getListsServer: function () {
           .
           .
           .
            var lists = ListsDB.find({"_id": { "$in": usersGroupList       }}).map(function (obj) {
                return {
                    "_id": obj._id,
                    "name": obj.name,
                    "groupId" :obj.groupId,
                    "incompleteCount": obj.incompleteCount
                };
            });

            return lists;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try removing the space in Session.set('getResults', result). If it doesn't work, do you return something in your method? Can you include your getListsServer method code too?

Comment: var shoppingLists = ShoppingListsDB.find({"_id": { "$in": usersGroupList }}).map(function (obj) {
            return {
                "_id": obj._id,
                "name": obj.name,
                "groupId" :obj.groupId,
                "incompleteCount": obj.incompleteCount
            };
        });
        //console.log('getGroupShoppingListsServer 6', shoppingLists);

        //console.log('GroupsDB.methods.getGroupShoppingLists 7', usersGroupList);
        return shoppingLists;

Comment: Ramil, here is the return object. This works fine if I move it into the validatedMethod getLists function.

Comment: I figured out that the result from the Meteor.call only goes to the server side of the validated-method and not the client simulation. I think this has to does with the async behavior. This probably requires using Fibers, but never having used them before and am not sure where to start. Can anyone help with getting the result to client inside a validated-method?

Comment: No, you can pass the error and result from Meteor.methods() to Meteor.call(). Do you want me to write an example? I don't use validatedMethod tho and I'm not sure if it will work for you.

Comment: Hi Luna, thank you for the offer, but I will live with doing everything inside the validatedMethod and give up on the Meteor.call.